# Why can NodeJS request set post form later using Chain API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-request

I am try to figure out why we can set the form for the post request using `.form` after I have called `request.post`.

This is the code snippet from official document

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
// or
request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'})
// or
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, 
function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })
```

I am confused about the second example `request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'})`.
In my opinion, it should not work because once request.post(...) has been called, the request will be sent. And then the call to `.form` is like you are setting the post form after the request has been sent. So how can this work ? Is there anything wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And then the call to .form is like you are setting the post form after the request has been sent. So how can this work ?

Apparently, when you do this:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload')
```

The request is not immediately sent.  Instead, it is registered (with a `setImmediate()` or `process.nextTick()`) to be sent on the next tick of the event loop.

So, when you execute `request(...).form({key:'value'})`, the `.form()` gets a chance to modify the request before it is sent.

In [the doc for `.post()`](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads), there is this statement that explains:

> For advanced cases, you can access the form-data object itself via r.form(). This can be modified until the request is fired on the next cycle of the event-loop. (Note that this calling form() will clear the currently set form data for that request.)

In that above statement, `r` is the return value from calling `request.post()` so `r.form()` refers to `request.post(...).form(...)` which is your specific situation.

And, in [the source code](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/request.js#L704) is this comment:

```
// start() is called once we are ready to send the outgoing HTTP request.
// this is usually called on the first write(), end() or on nextTick()
```